# Dynamically linking a shared library from a pybind11-wrapped code

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, pybind11

I am trying to add python bindings to a medium-sized C++ scientific code (some tens of thousands LOCs). I have managed to make it work without too many issues, but I have now incurred in an issue which I am incapable of solving myself. The code is organized as follows:

- All the classes and data structures are compiled in a library `libcommon.a`
- Executables are created by linking this library
- pybind11 is used to create a `core.so` python module

The bindings for the "main" parts work fine. Indeed, simulations launched from the standalone code or from python give the exact same results.

However, the code also supports a plugin-like system which can load shared libraries at runtime. These shared libraries contain classes that inherit from interfaces defined in the main code. It turns out that if I try to link these shared libraries from python I get the infamous "undefined symbol" errors. I have checked that these symbols are in the `core.so` module (using `nm -D`). In fact, simulations that perform the dynamic linking with the standalone code works perfectly (within the same folder and with the same input). Somehow, the shared lib cannot find the right symbols when called through python, but it has no issues when loaded by the standalone code. I am using CMake to build the system.

What follows is a MCE. Copy each file in a folder, copy (or link) the `pybind11` folder in the same place and use the following commands:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

which will generate a `standalone` binary and a python module. The `standalone` executable will produce the correct output. By contrast, using the following commands in python3 (that, at least in my head, should be equivalent) yields an error:

```py
import core
b = core.load_plugin()
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"
#include "plugin_loader.h"

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    Base *d = load_plugin();
    if(d == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "No lib found" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    d->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

### Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE
#define BASE

struct Base {
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();

    virtual void foo();
};

#endif
```

### Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"

#include <iostream>

Base::Base() {}

Base::~Base() {}

void Base::foo() {
    std::cout << "Hey, it's Base!" << std::endl;
}
```

### plugin_loader.h

```
#ifndef LOADER
#define LOADER

#include "Base.h"

Base *load_plugin();

#endif
```

### plugin_loader.cpp

```
#include "plugin_loader.h"

#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef Base* make_base();

Base *load_plugin() {
    void *handle = dlopen("./Derived.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);
    const char *dl_error = dlerror();
    if(dl_error != nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "Caught an error while opening shared library: " << dl_error << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    make_base *entry = (make_base *) dlsym(handle, "make");

    return (Base *) entry();
}
```

### Derived.h

```
#include "Base.h"

struct Derived : public Base {
    Derived();
    virtual ~Derived();
    void foo() override;
};

extern "C" Base *make() {
    return new Derived();
}
```

### Derived.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

#include <iostream>

Derived::Derived() {}

Derived::~Derived() {}

void Derived::foo() {
    std::cout << "Hey, it's Derived!" << std::endl;
}
```

### bindings.cpp

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

#include "Base.h"
#include "plugin_loader.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(core, m) {
        pybind11::class_<Base, std::shared_ptr<Base>> base(m, "Base");

        base.def(pybind11::init<>());
        base.def("foo", &Base::foo);

        m.def("load_plugin", &load_plugin);
}
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT(foobar)

# compile the library
ADD_LIBRARY(common SHARED Base.cpp plugin_loader.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(common ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(common PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

# compile the standalone code
ADD_EXECUTABLE(standalone main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(standalone common)

# compile the "plugin"
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX "")
ADD_LIBRARY(Derived SHARED Derived.cpp)

# compile the bindings
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(pybind11)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/pybind11/include )

FIND_PACKAGE( PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

ADD_LIBRARY(_oxpy_lib STATIC bindings.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(_oxpy_lib ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} common)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(_oxpy_lib PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

pybind11_add_module(core SHARED bindings.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(core PRIVATE _oxpy_lib)
```

Comment: There is nothing inherently problematic about the code that you posted. The error is most likely somewhere else. Please try to work out a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @ComicSansMS thanks for your comment. I have added a (pretty long, alas) MWE.

Comment: @lr1985 The `bindings.cpp` is missing

Comment: @Sergei thanks! I have added its contents to the question.

Comment: (side note: probably `bindings.cpp` should be excluded from `_oxyl_lib` sources)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, symbols from imported library are not visible because `core` loaded without `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag set. You can fix that with a couple of extra lines on python side:

```
import sys, os
sys.setdlopenflags(os.RTLD_GLOBAL | os.RTLD_LAZY)

import core
b = core.load_plugin()
```

From `sys.setdlopenflags()` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setdlopenflags):

> To share symbols across extension modules, call as `sys.setdlopenflags(os.RTLD_GLOBAL)`. Symbolic names for the flag values can be found in the `os` module (`RTLD_xxx` constants, e.g. `os.RTLD_LAZY`).